# How, when and what to vectorize in python?

Tags: python, c, numpy, latitude-longitude, cython

Right, so this is basically a follow up of an earlier question of mine. I have some binary data that are in floating point binary format. Using C, the process is ***fast***, but I lose some precision with atof(). I tried looking through the forum, and also elsewhere, but my problem was not solved. As such, I moved to python. Ah joy! the program worked perfectly well, but is ***so very slow*** compared to C. I looked up optimizations on python, which pointed me to Cython and Weave, but I have some doubts. If you will follow my code, I am confused where to apply the optimizing C code, since I am reading from the numpy object. My question, is it possible to read data using numpy functions within the Cython, and if so, please provide a small example.

*The C Code uses PolSARpro's header files, and libbmp for creating the .bmp file*

As a note, I am posting both my codes. God knows I had to go through a lot just to get the formulas working. This way, others in need can give their thoughts and input too :)

C Code (Working, but atof() loses precision, thus output lat long are slightly off)

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <polSARpro/bmpfile.c>
#include <polSARpro/graphics.c>
#include <polSARpro/matrix.c>
#include <polSARpro/processing.c>
#include <polSARpro/util.c>
#define METAL_THRESHOLD 5.000000
#define POLARIZATION_FRACTION_THRESHOLD 0.900000
#define PI 3.14159265
#define FOURTHPI PI/4
#define deg2rad PI/180
#define rad2deg 180./PI

/*double PI = 3.14159265;
double FOURTHPI = PI / 4;
double deg2rad = PI / 180;
double rad2deg = 180.0 / PI;*/

FILE *L1,*PF,*SPF;
FILE *txt;
FILE *finalLocations;
long i=0,loop_end;
int lig,col;
float l1,pf,spf;
long pos;
int Nlig,Ncol;

float *bufferout;
float *bufferin_L1,*bufferin_L2;
float valueL1,valuePF,xx;
float sizeGridX, sizeGridY, startX, startY;
float posX,posY;
int ZONE;
char Heading[10];
char setZone[15];

int p[4][2];

int degree, minute, second;

void UTM2LL(int ReferenceEllipsoid, double UTMNorthing, double UTMEasting, char* UTMZone, double *Lat, double *Long)
{
//converts UTM coords to lat/long.  Equations from USGS Bulletin 1532
//East Longitudes are positive, West longitudes are negative.
//North latitudes are positive, South latitudes are negative
//Lat and Long are in decimal degrees.
    //Written by Chuck Gantz- chuck.gantz@globalstar.com

    double k0 = 0.9996;
    double a = 6378137;
    double eccSquared =  0.00669438;
    double eccPrimeSquared;
    double e1 = (1-sqrt(1-eccSquared))/(1+sqrt(1-eccSquared));
    double N1, T1, C1, R1, D, M;
    double LongOrigin;
    double mu, phi1, phi1Rad;
    double x, y;
    int ZoneNumber;
    char* ZoneLetter;
    int NorthernHemisphere; //1 for northern hemispher, 0 for southern

    x = UTMEasting - 500000.0; //remove 500,000 meter offset for longitude
    y = UTMNorthing;

    ZoneNumber = strtoul(UTMZone, &ZoneLetter, 10);
    if((*ZoneLetter - 'N') >= 0)
        NorthernHemisphere = 1;//point is in northern hemisphere
    else
    {
        NorthernHemisphere = 0;//point is in southern hemisphere
        y -= 10000000.0;//remove 10,000,000 meter offset used for southern hemisphere
    }

    LongOrigin = (ZoneNumber - 1)*6 - 180 + 3;  //+3 puts origin in middle of zone

    eccPrimeSquared = (eccSquared)/(1-eccSquared);

    M = y / k0;
    mu = M/(a*(1-eccSquared/4-3*eccSquared*eccSquared/64-5*eccSquared*eccSquared*eccSquared/256));

    phi1Rad = mu    + (3*e1/2-27*e1*e1*e1/32)*sin(2*mu)
                + (21*e1*e1/16-55*e1*e1*e1*e1/32)*sin(4*mu)
                +(151*e1*e1*e1/96)*sin(6*mu);
    phi1 = phi1Rad*rad2deg;

    N1 = a/sqrt(1-eccSquared*sin(phi1Rad)*sin(phi1Rad));
    T1 = tan(phi1Rad)*tan(phi1Rad);
    C1 = eccPrimeSquared*cos(phi1Rad)*cos(phi1Rad);
    R1 = a*(1-eccSquared)/pow(1-eccSquared*sin(phi1Rad)*sin(phi1Rad), 1.5);
    D = x/(N1*k0);

    *Lat = phi1Rad - (N1*tan(phi1Rad)/R1)*(D*D/2-(5+3*T1+10*C1-4*C1*C1-9*eccPrimeSquared)*D*D*D*D/24
                    +(61+90*T1+298*C1+45*T1*T1-252*eccPrimeSquared-3*C1*C1)*D*D*D*D*D*D/720);
    *Lat = *Lat * rad2deg;

    *Long = (D-(1+2*T1+C1)*D*D*D/6+(5-2*C1+28*T1-3*C1*C1+8*eccPrimeSquared+24*T1*T1)
                    *D*D*D*D*D/120)/cos(phi1Rad);
    *Long = LongOrigin + *Long * rad2deg;
}

void convertToDegree(float decimal)
{
    int negative = decimal < 0;
    decimal = abs(decimal);
    minute = (decimal * 3600/ 60);
    second = fmodf((decimal * 3600),60);
    degree = minute / 60;
    minute = minute % 60;
    if (negative)
    {
        if (degree > 0)
            degree = -degree;
        else if (minute > 0)
            minute = -minute;
        else
            second = -second;
    }
}

void readConfig(int *Row, int *Col)
{
    char tmp[70];
    int i=0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("config.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Config.txt");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fgets(tmp,70,fp);
        if (i==1)
            *Row = atoi(tmp);
        if(i==4)
            *Col = atoi(tmp);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void readHDR(float *gridX,float *gridY,float *startXPos,float *startYPos)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("PF.bin.hdr","r");
    int i=0;
    char tmp[255];
    char junk[255];
    memset(tmp,0X00,sizeof(tmp));
    memset(junk,0X00,sizeof(junk));
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        perror("Please locate or create PF.bin.hdr");
        exit(0);
    }
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        if(i==13)
            break;
        fgets(tmp,255,fp);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    strcpy(junk,strtok(tmp,","));
    strtok(NULL,",");
    strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(tmp,strtok(NULL,","));
    //puts(tmp);
    *startXPos = atof(tmp);
    strcpy(tmp,strtok(NULL,","));
    //puts(tmp);
    *startYPos = atof(tmp);
    strcpy(tmp,strtok(NULL,","));
    //puts(tmp);
    *gridX = atof(tmp);
    strcpy(tmp,strtok(NULL,","));
    //puts(tmp);
    *gridY = atof(tmp);
    strcpy(tmp,strtok(NULL,","));
    ZONE = atoi(tmp);
    strcpy(tmp,strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(Heading,tmp);
}

int main()
{
    bmpfile_t *bmp;
    double Lat;
    double Long;
    int i;
    rgb_pixel_t pixelMetal = {128, 64, 0, 0};
    rgb_pixel_t pixelOthers = {128, 64, 0, 0};
    readConfig(&Nlig,&Ncol);
    readHDR(&sizeGridX,&sizeGridY,&startX,&startY);
    //startX = startX - (double) 0.012000;
    //startY = startY + (double)0.111000;
    printf("Enter the rectangle's top-left and bottom-right region of interest points as: x y\n");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter point %d::\t",i+1);
        scanf("%d %d",&p[i][0], &p[i][1]);
    }
    printf("Grid Size(X,Y)::( %f,%f ), Start Positions(X,Y)::( %f, %f ), ZONE::%d, Heading:: %s\n\n",sizeGridX,sizeGridY,startX,startY,ZONE,Heading);
    pixelMetal.red = 255;
    pixelMetal.blue = 010;
    pixelMetal.green = 010;
    pixelOthers.red = 8;
    pixelOthers.blue = 8;
    pixelOthers.green = 8;
    L1 = fopen("l1.bin","rb");
    PF =fopen("PF.bin","rb");
    SPF = fopen("SPF_L1.bin","wb");
    //txt = fopen("locations(UTM).txt","w");
    finalLocations = fopen("locationsROI.txt","w");
    if(L1==NULL || PF==NULL || SPF==NULL || finalLocations == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error in opening files!");
        return -1;
    }
    fseek(L1,0,SEEK_END);
    pos = ftell(L1);
    loop_end = pos;
    printf("L1.bin contains::\t%ld elements\n",pos);
    fseek(PF,0,SEEK_END);
    pos = ftell(PF);
    printf("PF.bin contains::\t%ld elements\n",pos);
    fseek(L1,0,SEEK_SET);
    fseek(PF,0,SEEK_SET);
    bmp = bmp_create(Ncol,Nlig,8); //width * height
    bufferin_L1 = vector_float(Ncol);
    bufferin_L2 = vector_float(Ncol);
    bufferout = vector_float(Ncol);
    printf("Resources Allocated. Beginning...\n");
    for (lig = 0; lig < Nlig; lig++) /* rows */
    {
        if (lig%(int)(Nlig/20) == 0)
        {
            printf("%f\r", 100. * lig / (Nlig - 1));
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        fread(&bufferin_L1[0], sizeof(float), Ncol, L1);
        fread(&bufferin_L2[0], sizeof(float), Ncol, PF);
        for (col = 0; col < Ncol; col++) /* columns */
        {
            valueL1 = bufferin_L1[col];
            valuePF = bufferin_L2[col];
            if(valueL1 >= METAL_THRESHOLD && valuePF >= POLARIZATION_FRACTION_THRESHOLD)
            {
                if(col >= p[0][0] && col <= p[1][0] && lig >= p[0][1] && lig <= p[1][1])
                {
                    xx = fabs(valueL1 + valuePF);
                    bmp_set_pixel(bmp,col,lig,pixelMetal);
                    posX = startX + (sizeGridX * col);
                    posY = startY - (sizeGridY * lig);
                    //fprintf(txt,"%f %f %d %s\n",posX,posY,ZONE,Heading);
                    sprintf(setZone,"%d",ZONE);
                    if(strstr(Heading,"Nor")!=NULL)
                        strcat(setZone,"N");
                    else
                        strcat(setZone,"S");
                    UTM2LL(23, posY, posX, setZone, &Lat, &Long); // 23 for WGS-84
                    convertToDegree(Lat);
                    //fprintf(finalLocations,"UTM:: %.2fE %.2fN , Decimal: %f %f , Degree: %d %d %d, ",posX,posY,Lat,Long,degree,minute,second);
                    //fprintf(finalLocations,"%.2fE,%.2fN,%f,%f ,%d,%d,%d,",posX,posY,Lat,Long,degree,minute,second);
                    fprintf(finalLocations,"%.2f,%.2f,%f,%f ,%d,%d,%d,",posX,posY,Lat,Long,degree,minute,second);
                    convertToDegree(Long);
                    fprintf(finalLocations,"%d,%d,%d\n",degree,minute,second);
                }
                else
                {
                    xx = fabs(valueL1) ;
                    bmp_set_pixel(bmp,col,lig,pixelOthers);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                xx = fabs(valueL1) ;
                bmp_set_pixel(bmp,col,lig,pixelOthers);
            }
            bufferout[col] = xx;
        }
        fwrite(&bufferout[0], sizeof(float), Ncol, SPF);
    }
    free_vector_float(bufferout);
    fclose(L1);
    fclose(PF);
    fclose(SPF);
    //fclose(txt);
    fclose(finalLocations);
    printf("\n----------Writing BMP File!----------\n");
    bmp_save(bmp,"SPF_L1(ROI).bmp");
    bmp_destroy(bmp);
    printf("\nDone!\n");
}
```

---

As well as the Python code::

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Apr 10 10:29:18 2013

@author: Binayaka
"""
import numpy as Num;
import math;
import array;

class readConfiguration(object):  

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.readConfig(x);

    def readConfig(self,x):
        try:
            crs = open(x,'r');
            srs = open('config.txt','r');
        except IOError:
            print "Files missing!";
        else:
            rows = crs.readlines();                
            values = rows[12].split(',');
            rows = srs.readlines();                
            self.startX = float(values[3]);
            self.startY = float(values[4]);
            self.gridSizeX = float(values[5]);
            self.gridSizeY = float(values[6]);
            self.Zone = int(values[7]);
            self.Hemisphere = values[8];
            self.NRows = int(rows[1].strip());
            self.NCols = int(rows[4].strip());
            self.MetalThreshold = 5.000000;
            self.PFThreshold = 0.900000;
            self.rad2deg = 180/math.pi;
            self.deg2rad = math.pi/180;
            self.FOURTHPI = math.pi/4;
            crs.close();
            srs.close();

    def decdeg2dms(dd):
        negative = dd < 0;
        dd = abs(dd);
        minutes,seconds = divmod(dd*3600,60);
        degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes,60);
        if negative:
            if degrees > 0:
                degrees = -degrees;
            elif minutes > 0:
                    minutes = -minutes;
        else:
            seconds = -seconds;
        return (degrees,minutes,seconds);

    def UTM2LL(self,UTMEasting, UTMNorthing):
        k0 = 0.9996;
        a = 6378137;
        eccSquared =  0.00669438;
        e1 = (1-math.sqrt(1-eccSquared))/(1+math.sqrt(1-eccSquared));
        x = UTMEasting - 500000.0;#remove 500,000 meter offset for longitude
        y = UTMNorthing;
        if self.Hemisphere == "North":
            self.Hemi = 1;
        else:
            self.Hemi = -1;
            y -= 10000000.0;
        LongOrigin = (self.Zone - 1)*6 - 180 + 3;
        eccPrimeSquared = (eccSquared)/(1-eccSquared);
        M = y / k0;
        mu = M/(a*(1-eccSquared/4-3*eccSquared*eccSquared/64-5*eccSquared*eccSquared*eccSquared/256));
        phi1Rad = mu    + (3*e1/2-27*e1*e1*e1/32)*math.sin(2*mu) + (21*e1*e1/16-55*e1*e1*e1*e1/32)*math.sin(4*mu) +(151*e1*e1*e1/96)*math.sin(6*mu);
        #phi1 = phi1Rad*self.rad2deg;
        N1 = a/math.sqrt(1-eccSquared*math.sin(phi1Rad)*math.sin(phi1Rad));
        T1 = math.tan(phi1Rad)*math.tan(phi1Rad);
        C1 = eccPrimeSquared*math.cos(phi1Rad)*math.cos(phi1Rad);
        R1 = a*(1-eccSquared)/pow(1-eccSquared*math.sin(phi1Rad)*math.sin(phi1Rad), 1.5);
        D = x/(N1*k0);
        self.Lat = phi1Rad - (N1*math.tan(phi1Rad)/R1)*(D*D/2-(5+3*T1+10*C1-4*C1*C1-9*eccPrimeSquared)*D*D*D*D/24   +(61+90*T1+298*C1+45*T1*T1-252*eccPrimeSquared-3*C1*C1)*D*D*D*D*D*D/720);
        self.Lat = self.Lat * self.rad2deg;
        self.Long = (D-(1+2*T1+C1)*D*D*D/6+(5-2*C1+28*T1-3*C1*C1+8*eccPrimeSquared+24*T1*T1)*D*D*D*D*D/120)/math.cos(phi1Rad);
        self.Long = LongOrigin + self.Long * self.rad2deg;   

    def printConfiguration(self):        
        """ Just to check whether our reading was correct """
        print "Metal Threshold:\t" + str(self.MetalThreshold);        
        print "PF    Threshold:\t" + str(self.PFThreshold);
        print "Start         X:\t" + str(self.startX);
        print "Start         Y:\t" + str(self.startY);
        print "Grid size(X)   :\t" + str(self.gridSizeX);
        print "Grid size(Y)   :\t" + str(self.gridSizeY);

    def createROIfile(self,ROIFilename):
        firstPoint = raw_input('Enter topLeft point coord\t').split();
        secondPoint = raw_input('Enter bottomRight point coord\t').split();
        try:
            L1 = open('l1.bin','rb');
            PF = open('PF.bin','rb');
            SPF = open('pySPF_L1.bin','wb');
            targetFilename = open(ROIFilename,'w');
        except IOError:
            print "Files Missing!";
        else:
            L1.seek(0,2);
            elementsL1 = L1.tell();
            L1.seek(0,0);
            PF.seek(0,2);
            elementsPF = PF.tell();
            PF.seek(0,0);
            print "L1.bin contains\t" + str(elementsL1) + " elements";
            print "PF.bin contains\t" + str(elementsPF) + " elements";
            binvaluesL1 = array.array('f');
            binvaluesPF = array.array('f');
            binvaluesSPF = array.array('f');            
            for row in range(0,self.NRows):                                
                binvaluesL1.read(L1,self.NCols);
                binvaluesPF.read(PF,self.NCols);
                dataL1 = Num.array(binvaluesL1, dtype=Num.float);
                dataPF = Num.array(binvaluesPF, dtype=Num.float);
                dataSPF = dataL1 + dataPF;
                binvaluesSPF.fromlist(Num.array(dataSPF).tolist());                                
                for col in range(0,self.NCols):                     
                    if(dataL1[col] >= self.MetalThreshold and dataPF[col] >= self.PFThreshold):
                        if(col >= int(firstPoint[0]) and col <= int(secondPoint[0]) and row >= int(firstPoint[1]) and row <= int(secondPoint[1])):
                            posX = self.startX + (self.gridSizeX * col);                         
                            posY = self.startY - (self.gridSizeY * row);
                            self.UTM2LL(posY,posX);
                            tmp1 = self.decdeg2dms(posY);
                            tmp2 = self.decdeg2dms(posX);
                            strTarget = "Decimal Degree:: " + str(posX) + "E " + str(posY) + "N \t Lat long:: " + str(tmp1) + " " + str(tmp2) + "\n";
                            targetFilename.write(strTarget);
                binvaluesSPF.tofile(SPF);
            L1.close();
            PF.close();
            SPF.close();
            targetFilename.close();
            print "Done!";

dimensions = readConfiguration('PF.bin.hdr');
dimensions.printConfiguration();
dimensions.createROIfile('testPythonROI.txt');
```

---

Its the Python code that needs Optimization, as the values of NRows and NCols can and do reach the order of thousands.

Comment: You are concerned with precision but return the result of `atof` to a float. Can't you use double type?

Comment: i can't answer the question, but take a look at shedskin (and the examples to get started), its a python to c++ translator/compiler, you can compile the resulting c++ program and it is blazing fast :)

Comment: @suspectus: First thing I tried, didn't work :( Then I read that this behavior of atof() is very common! But my problem was that atof() couldn't even return 3 places after decimal!

Comment: @Binayaka That suggests to me there is an error in the computation.

Comment: I don't think too many people are going to actually read your 100+ lines of code, I know I am not. I'd suggest you isolate the source of your worries, whether it is the working of `atof` or the bottleneck in your Python code (after profiling it), then prepare a short, self contained example that illustrates your problem and ask for help here. You will get much more feedback, plus you'll often find that preparing a good question often leads to answering it on your own. Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about performance, but you really shouldn't "roll your own" when it comes to projections. Even if you get everything right, your code produces lat, longs referenced to an ellipsoid. Essentially every other lat, long you'll see will be referenced to a datum (usually WGS84).  You'll have >1km shifts in many areas between the two.  I'd recommend `pyproj` (which is a python wrapper for Proj4) for python, and Proj4 is the standard library for C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few general comments:

1. With python, it's really best to stick to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a multitude of reasons. Python programmers are particularly picky about readability and essentially universally adhere to the community coding guidelines (PEP8).  Avoid camelCase, keep lines below 80 columns, leave the semicolons out, and feel free to occasionally ignore these guidelines where they'd make things less readable.
2. There's no need for the builtin `array` type here if you're using numpy.  I'm confused why you're constantly converting back and forth...
3. Use a projection library.  Specify what datum and ellipsoid you're using, otherwise the coordinates (easting/northing or lat/long) have absolutely no meaning.
4. Don't use one big class as a hold-all for unrelated things. There's nothing wrong with just having a few functions. You don't need to make it into a class unless it makes sense to do so.
5. Use vectorized operations with numpy arrays.

Here's what would appear to be your performance bottleneck:

```
    for row in range(0,self.NRows):                                
        binvaluesL1.read(L1,self.NCols);
        binvaluesPF.read(PF,self.NCols);
        dataL1 = Num.array(binvaluesL1, dtype=Num.float);
        dataPF = Num.array(binvaluesPF, dtype=Num.float);
        dataSPF = dataL1 + dataPF;
        binvaluesSPF.fromlist(Num.array(dataSPF).tolist());                                
        for col in range(0,self.NCols):                     
            if(dataL1[col] >= self.MetalThreshold and dataPF[col] >= self.PFThreshold):
                if(col >= int(firstPoint[0]) and col <= int(secondPoint[0]) and row >= int(firstPoint[1]) and row <= int(secondPoint[1])):
                    posX = self.startX + (self.gridSizeX * col);                         
                    posY = self.startY - (self.gridSizeY * row);
                    self.UTM2LL(posY,posX);
                    tmp1 = self.decdeg2dms(posY);
                    tmp2 = self.decdeg2dms(posX);
                    strTarget = "Decimal Degree:: " + str(posX) + "E " + str(posY) + "N \t Lat long:: " + str(tmp1) + " " + str(tmp2) + "\n";
                    targetFilename.write(strTarget);
        binvaluesSPF.tofile(SPF);
```

One of your biggest problems is the way you're reading in your data.  You're constantly reading things in as one thing, then converting that to a list, then converting that to a numpy array. There's absolutely no need to jump through all those hoops. Numpy will unpack your binary floats for you just like `array` will.

Just do `grid = np.fromfile(yourfile, dtype=np.float32).reshape(ncols, nrows)`. (Outside the loop.)

After that, your nested loops can be easily vectorized and expressed with just a few lines of code.

Here's how I would write your code. This probably won't run as-is, as I can't test it with your data. However, it should give you some general ideas.

```
import numpy as np
import pyproj

def main():
    config = Config('PF.bin.hdr')
    grid1, grid2 = load_data('l1.bin', 'PF.bin', config.nrows, config.ncols)

    spf = grid1 + grid2
    spf.tofile('pySPF_L1.bin')

    easting_aoi, northing_aoi = subset_data(grid1, grid2, config)
    save_selected_region(easting_aoi, northing_aoi, config.zone, 
                        'testPythonROI.txt')

def load_data(filename1, filename2, nrows, ncols):
    """It would really be good to use more descriptive variable names than "L1"
    and "PF".  I have no idea what L1 and PF are, so I'm just calling them
    grid1 and grid2."""
    grid1 = np.fromfile(filename1, dtype=np.float32).reshape(nrows, ncols)
    grid2 = np.fromfile(filename2, dtype=np.float32).reshape(nrows, ncols)
    return grid1, grid2

def subset_data(grid1, grid2, config):
    """Select points that satisfy some threshold criteria (explain??) and are
    within a user-specified rectangular AOI."""
    northing, easting = np.mgrid[:config.nrows, :config.ncols]
    easting = config.xstart + config.xgridsize * easting
    northing = config.ystart + config.ygridsize * northing

    grids = grid1, grid2, easting, northing
    grid1, grid2, easting, northing = [item[config.user_aoi] for item in grids]

    mask = (grid1 >= config.metal_threshold) & (grid2 >= config.pf_threshold)
    return easting[mask], northing[mask]

def save_selected_region(easting, northing, zone, filename):
    """Convert the given eastings and northings (in UTM zone "zone") to 
    lat/long and save to a tab-delimited-text file."""
    lat, lon = utm2geographic(easting, northing, zone)
    data = np.vstack([easting, northing, lat, lon]).T
    with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write('Easting\tNorthing\tLatitude\tLongitude\n')
        np.savetxt(outfile, data, delimiter='\t')

def utm2geographic(easting, northing, zone):
    """We need to know which datum/ellipsoid the UTM coords are in as well!!!!
    I'm assuming it's a Clark 1866 ellipsoid, based on the numbers in your
    code..."""
    utm = pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=zone, ellip='clrk66')
    geographic = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellip='clrk66')
    return pyproj.transform(utm, geographic, easting, northing)

class Config(object):
    """Read and store configuration values for (something?)."""
    config_file = 'config.txt'
    def __init__(self, filename):
        """You should add docstrings to clarify what you're expecting 
        "filename" to contain."""
        with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
            crs_values = list(infile)[12].split(',')
        crs_values = [float(item) for item in crs_values]
        self.xstart, self.ystart = crs_values[3:5]
        self.xgridsize, self.ygridsize = crs_values[5:7]
        self.zone = int(crs_values[7])

        with open(self.config_file, 'r') as infile:
            srs_values = list(infile)
        self.nrows, self.ncols = srs_values[1], srs_values[4]

        # It would be good to explain a bit about these (say, units, etc)
        self.metal_threshold = 5.0
        self.pf_threshold = 0.9

        self.user_aoi = self.read_user_aoi()

    def read_user_aoi(self):
        """Get an area of interest of the grids in pixel coordinates."""
        top_left = raw_input('Enter top left index\t')
        bottom_right = raw_input('Enter bottom right index\t')
        min_i, min_j = [int(item) for item in top_left.split()]
        max_i, max_j = [int(item) for item in bottom_right.split()]
        return slice(min_i, max_i), slice(min_j, max_j)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the pyproj! Actually, this is the first time I used numpy, so I had no idea about how to do the operation, apart from literal translation from the C Code. Oh, and PF stands for Polarization Fraction, and L1 is for 1st eigenvalue decomposition :)

Comment: Glad you found it useful! :) `numpy` is a big library, so it takes some getting used to. Also, I just fixed one rather stupid mistake in my example. There are probably lots of others! Hopefully it's still useful, though.

Comment: A little detail: In Python 2: list comprehensions like `[float(item) for item in crs_values]` can simply be written as the shorter and as legible `map(float, crs_values)`.